# Picture from facebook album

Tags: facebook, angular, cordova-plugins, ionic2, photos

(Notice: this question include ionic2 and cordova tags, but if you know only **angular** - may be you can also help me!)

I build ionic application (version 2 of ionic and version 2 of angular).

I search a lot after option of cordova-camera-plugin for **let user choose photo from his facebook-album**, for disaply it to other app-users.

Is there any way to do it?

Or is there other way to do that, not by cordova-camera?

Comment: you quite possibly will need to use the facebook javascript SDK, using their rest api you can get photo's but not sure (that's why this is a comment)

Comment: If you have code sample - it can be very helpfull